# bash script to generate iso-time from output of older BSD-`ls`

Tags: bash, date, timestamp, ls, iso

I would like to generate an iso-style time info (YYYY-MM-DDTmm:hh:ss) on
a bsd-ish system with an older `ls` command (`man` states it's a
BSD-ls) and no `--time-style` option. The best I get is

```
$ ls -lT log.out
-rw-r--r--  1 admin4  staff  49152 Jul 17 09:38:38 2018 log.out
```

Is there a simple way to transform this time information within a
bash-script into iso-style?

```
$ timestamp="$(ls -lT log.out | iso-timestamp-gen)"
```

Your help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve our problem

```
timestamp="$(ls -lT log.out | iso-timestamp-gen)"
```

@Hamidreza pointed us into the direktion of the `date` command: One
of our engineers came up with this slender inline solution:

```
timestamp=$(date -j -f '%b %e %T %Y' \
    "$(ls -lT $f | awk '{ print $6, $7, $8, $9 }')" \
    +'%F_%T')
```

where the variable `f` contains the name of the file to be considered.
In line 2 `awk` extracts the date-part (fields 6 upto 9) from the output of `ls -lT`.

Together with this "DateToConvert" `date` is fed a matching
input format `"%b %e %T %Y"`
and the requested output format `"%F_%T"`.
We looked up the conversion specifications in
strftime(3).

Up to now neither of us was aware that you could use `date` not only for
reading and setting the system clock but also for converting dates from
one format to another format:

```
date -j -f "${InputFormat}" "${DateToConvert}" +"${OutputFormat}"
```

With some embarassment we confessed this to each other and
decided to make good use of the new insight.
A couple of hours later we added the following new helper to our toolbox.
It extracts the date from the output of `ls -lT` and converts it to
other formats.  So far we included only the iso-format and a format
which is handy when using the touch(1) command. This list may be expanded in the future.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# conv-date-of-llT.sh
#   convert date output of ls -lT ($OSTYPE == darwin14)
#       - to iso-format YYYY-MM-DD_hh:mm:ss or
#       - to "touch" format: [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]
#
# hppo, 2018-07-20

# strip $0 of path and ext
Arg0="${0##*/}"     # peel off path
Arg0="${Arg0%%.*}"  # peel off ext

USAGE="${Arg0} [ -iso | -touch ]"

# select output format
case "fmt$1" in
    fmt|fmt-iso|fmtiso)     # YYYY-MM-DD_hh:mm:ss
        OutputFormat="%F_%T" ;;
    fmt-touch|fmttouch)     # YYYYMMDDhhmm
        OutputFormat="%Y%m%d%H%M" ;;
    *)
        1>&2 echo -e "${Arg0}: no such output format '$1'\nUsage: ${USAGE}"; exit 1 ;;
esac

# input: output of "ls -lT file" on darwin-14
#       -rwxr-xr-x  1 admin4  staff  387 Jul 17 01:38:24 2018 file
#       1       2 3   4  5   6   7  8        9    10
#
# Field 6 - 9: month(%b) day(%e) time(%T) year(%Y), cf strftime(3)
InputFormat="%b %e %T %Y"

# assume stdin is fed by output of ls -lT
DateToConvert="$(awk '{ print $6, $7, $8, $9 }')"

date -j -f "${InputFormat}" "${DateToConvert}" +"${OutputFormat}"
```

Answer (score 1):

first, `cut` out date part:

```
DATE=`echo - | cut -f9-12 -d' '`;
```

then convert it to timestamp using `date`:

```
echo `date --date="$DATE" +"%s"`;
```

the `iso-timestamp-gen` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=`echo - | cut -f9-12 -d' '`;
echo `date --date="$DATE" +"%s"`;
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts. You pointed us into the right direction - use `date` to convert a date... We read the manual and were able to fil in the gaps

Comment: many thanks again for you efforts. Your suggestion didn't work on our systems (our date doesn't understand `--date`) but you pointed us into the right direction!